# Sort an array of pointers in C

Tags: c

So I have a custom data type 'Medicine'. I also created an array where I store not instances of this data type, but pointers to instances of this data type. So each element from the array points to an instance of the data type. I want to sort this array using the name of each medicine. I have already done it using a selection sort that I wrote, but I'm trying to do it using the `qsort` function, so that I shorten the code. The problem is that I can't figure out how to write the `compare` function which I need to pass to the `qsort` function. It's not as easy as usual, since as I said I don't have instances in the array but rather pointers to instances of the array. This is the code that I wrote:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    Medicine *m1 = *((Medicine **) a);
    Medicine *m2 = *((Medicine **) b);
    if (strcmp(get_medicine_name(m1), get_medicine_name(m2)) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void sort_medicine_descending_name(DynamicArray *meds) {
    qsort(meds, get_dynamic_array_size(meds), sizeof(Medicine*), compare);
}
```

When I run this code I get a segmentation fault. I am positive that I don't have bugs in other parts of my code since I have quite a few other functions and they all work fine. I think my problem is when I try to cast and dereference those void pointers (although I am not sure). My logic behind it went something like this: Since I have pointers to Medicine in my array I need to type cast the arguments `a` and `b` as pointer to pointer, and then dereference them so that I get the pointers to Medicine. But since it didn't work, my intuition was clearly wrong. I'm still not fully competent when it comes to working with pointers, so I don't really know why this is not right, nor what I should do instead.

This is my implementation for Dynamic Array:

```
typedef struct {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void **elems;
} DynamicArray;
```

I create instances of this dynamic array using the following "constructor":

```
DynamicArray *create_dynamic_array(int capacity) {
    DynamicArray *da = (DynamicArray *) malloc(sizeof(DynamicArray));
    da->capacity = capacity;
    da->size = 0;
    da->elems = (void**) malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity);
    return da;
}
```

The way I wanted to write it is so that a dynamic array can store any type of elements. That's why `da->elems` is a pointer to pointer of void. This way I can just store the pointer to any data type in the dynamic array. So I can store the meds in a dynamic array by storing pointers to instances of `Medicine` (which, by the way, is also dynamically allocated). `da->capacity` is the capacity of the dynamic array, and whenever the array gets filled the capacity increases. `da->size` is the current number of elements in the dynamic array, which increases whenever I add an element to it and decreases whenever I remove an element.

I get the size of the dynamic using the following function:

```
int get_dynamic_array_size(DynamicArray *da) {
    return da->size;
}
```

Finally, the "class" `Medicine` stores, among other things, a dynamically allocated char array where the name is stored. `get_medicine_name()` takes as argument a pointer to medicine and returns the pointer to this char array.

Comment: What's a `DynamicArray`?  What's `get_dynamic_array_size()`? What's `get_medicine_name()`?  I'm inclined to suspect that the problem is that `meds` is not the correct first argument to `qsort()`, but we really need a [mre] to figure this out.

Comment: *I am positive that I don't have bugs in other parts*. Famous last words. That might be true (or it may not). But we need to verify it for ourselves. So you need to provide complete code. In this case we need to see `get_dynamic_array_size`, `DynamicArray`, how the function is called and any other missing bits needed for a complete example.

Comment: That comparator is broken even as is. < 0 for "less", > 0 for "greater" *and* = 0 for equivalence. You seem to be missing the latter. Regardless, without a proper [mcve] (which should be trivial enough to craft), you're gonna get nothing by sheer speculation and WAGs (wild-arse-guesses), neither of which is proper for this forum.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right. I'm sorry. I added details. Let me know if I should add anything else.

Comment: @kaylum I added details about my implementation. If it's still not enough, please let me know.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the post. Please let me know if anything else is still missing.

Comment: @abcxyz Well, obviously the first thing wrong is passing `meds` to `qsort`. That's completely broken. You're not sorting `meds`, you're sorting `meds->elems`

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right. I'm an idiot :) It works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is, that `qsort` assumes that it gets an array of equal types.
But you pass your root structure to that. So your `compare` function gets the `size` and `capacity` member as the pointer, that surely cause a segfault.

Instead you should pass the `elem` array.

```
qsort(meds->elem, meds->size, sizeof(*meds->elem), compare);
```